# How to get consistence rendering of <p> paragraph text in all browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml, cross-browser

How to get consistence rendering of

paragraph text in all browsers?

See IE 7 rendering like this

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/248/0266470505.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/248/0266470505.jpg)

and FF like this . which is ok to client

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/248/8655561297.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/248/8655561297.jpg)

How to get same result in both browsers, i mean FF rendering in IE? my client needs "non-executive" in same line in all browsers, Is `<br />` only solution of this.

Update : see all code for `<p>` here http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/248/4505395091.jpg

I'm already using XHTML 1.1 doctype and eric meyer reset CSS

**Update: 28 March**

Thanks for all replies!

I tested this problem is only not coming on firefox . but coming in all other browser IE6, 7, 8, Safari(windows), Google Chrome.

Is there any possibility css only solution now?

Answer (score 2):

For your specific issue, use the `<nobr>` tag around your text, or a span with the CSS

```
whitespace: no-wrap;
```

This will prevent non-executive from breaking across lines.

However, you should note that getting entirely consistent rendering is quite difficult between browsers and platforms.

Comment: There is also the possibility to use non-breaking hyphens. The unicode is *U+2011*.

Comment: Ah, non-breaking hyphen is probably a better solution.  `&#8209;` in html/decimal notation.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You are most likely setting both a fixed width *and* a padding on the left and right of the element. IE and Firefox will interpret that differently due to box model differences. If you cannot recode your page to use a fixed width and a left/right margin, then you will need to specify a different fixed width in an IE only stylesheet to compensate for the problem.

**Education**

Web development is about education. Much of that education is educating your client on what to expect and not to expect.

Help by explaining to your client that each browser, and OS combination handle fonts a little differently. One engine may place the letters slightly closer to each other than another.

You could put tons of work into getting this just right, but if your end user has enlarged their fonts at all, all the time and money spent on making sure one hyphenated word stays on the same line will go out the window.

**Technical Thought:** Both browsers appear to already be rendering the text as closely as they can, I don't think a `reset.css` is going to help you at all.

Comment: I realize this might not have been a technical answer at first, but can the down-voter explain what part of what I said was wrong?

Comment: Not that I'm a downvoter, but I believe that this is a case where the exact same layout _cannot_ be achieved, because text isn't rendered the same on different browsers/platforms.

Comment: LOL... anytime someone challenges a downvote, everyone else is scared to answer.. sorry about that @Georg! What you are saying is what I was trying to get across, though the width of the interior of two text areas appears different as I mentioned on the comments of @cletus's answer. However, in general, text manipulation at this level is a waste of time.

Comment: Cletus' answer seems to have been downvoted as well for no reason, so you're in good company. I get the feeling that sometimes people downvote just because they can, or so.

Comment: Yes I got downvoted too. It seems to happen a lot when there are several similar answers with few upvotes. Someone decides to change the random order with anon downvotes. I think the random order makes this worse.

Comment: @cletus totally agree with you on the random thing. Its frustrating. It should be by vote, then time posted... or something. Your answer was great, I don't know why anyone would downvote it.

Comment: In this case it's a good thing to make the hyphen non-breaking. It increases the legibility. That's why I think McPherrinM's answer is the most helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting all styles to get rid of the differences in the browser stylesheets might be a good idea. YUI's [reset.css](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) can do this for you. then you can start from scratch to format your paragraphs, using percentages for font size , spacing etc. (see [YUI CSS cheatsheet](http://yuiblog.com/assets/pdf/cheatsheets/css.pdf)).

EDIT: Just saw your comment to cletus' answer. So: what CSS are you using for laying out your text?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with margins, padding, fonts, resets or any CSS, really. It's about how browsers interpret hyphens. IE obviously decides that it can break the line on a hyphen, whereas Firefox treats it as one word.

Like McPherrinM said, you can use no-break tag: `<nobr>non-executive</nobr>`. Or you could simply remove the hyphen altogether.

Or you could just explain to your client how all browsers and systems render text differently and there is no way you can prevent this occurring in all situations. What is the problem with the word splitting over two lines anyway?

Comment: I agree with the "who cares" attitude for the line breaking off at one word instead of the other, but that still doesn't solve the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the use of a soft hyphen
    &shy

Comment: but it need editing in content. and content is very huge site is very big